# The Frobenius of triangular numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

Given 3 consecutive triangular numbers - $T_n, T_{n+1},$ and $T_{n+2}$ - I'd like to know if there's an expression in $n$ for the largest number that can't be made from their sums.

For example, choosing $n=3$ gives us $T_3=6, T_4=10,$ and $T_5=15$. Their Frobenius number is $29$ since the equation
$$aT_3+bT_4+cT_5=29$$
has no solution when $a,b,$ and $c$ are restricted to be non-negative (positif!) integers.

$\bullet\textbf{Results}$

I've calculated
$$n=1\rightarrow 0$$
$$n=2\rightarrow 17$$
$$n=3\rightarrow 29$$
$$n=4\rightarrow 89$$

If two numbers $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then their Frobenius is [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) $ab-a-b$. It is also unknown in general if there is an expression for the Frobenius of $3$ numbers. I'm hoping that the constraint of consecutive triangular numbers is enough to yield an expression here.

$\bullet\textbf{Existence}$

Sometimes any $2$ of $T_n, T_{n+1},$ and $T_{n+2}$ is not relatively prime. But in all cases we have $gcd(T_n, T_{n+1}, T_{n+2})=1$. Thus according to [Shur's Thorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem) apparently the Frobenius of all $3$ exists.

$\bullet\textbf{Current Attempt}$

I've been using the fact that $T_{n+1} = T_n + n + 1$ and $T_{n+2} = T_n + 2n + 3$ to show
$$aT_n+bT_{n+1}+cT_{n+2}=(a+b+c)T_n+(b+2c)n + b+3c$$
$$:=AT_n+Bn+C$$
$$\text{where}$$
$$A=a+b+c \quad B = b+2c \quad C = b+3c$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$a,b,c\ge0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad C\ge B \quad 3B\ge 2C \quad A+C \ge 2B$$

Comment: If you have a triple $a,b,c$ you can look at the Frobenius number of each pair, what do you obtain in the case of triangular numbers ?

Comment: I think you mean the largest number that can't be made from their sums, not the smallest.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A069755](https://oeis.org/A069755).